# Difficulty using CircuitLab to build a Zener Diode Voltage Regulator Circuit

Tags: voltage, diodes, voltage-regulator, zener, circuitlab

So I'm trying to build a Zener Diode Voltage Regulator in CircuitLab.

I've been searching around Google for some insight into building these, however, I'm required to use a triangle wave input, while the examples I've been seeing online do not.

Basically, my issue is that when I run the simulation, I get an input/output voltage of 0, even though I set my input to 10V.

I suspect something simple is going wrong here, apologies for the lack of in-depth information to debug this issue, I'm just getting started building circuits.

Here's the circuit I've built that is giving me issues:
[image: Circuit Lab]

Thanks in advance for any guidance you guys can provide me!

Comment: um, you shorted your diode and RL out with the piece of connection where you added your "Vout" label.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because shortening out the relevant components is the schematics equivalent to a typo.

Comment: why did you include a picture of the circuit? ... you could have included the actual circuit that could be edited ... there is a button for including the circuit

Comment: @MarcusMüller So we only answer questions where the asker has not made a mistake? Maybe someone else will do the same thing in the future and find this post while googling?

Comment: @Drew nonono! The idea is the same as StackOverflows "this question is just based on a mistyping" close reason: The comment answers the question, so the asker has been helped, but since it's an honest, but random mistake, nobody else stands to learn from this, and it really isn't that much enlightenment once you see it that it 100% warrants an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'll bite.

The connection across RL (which you're tagged as 'Vout' in your diagram) is a mistake. The extra wire is shorting your output to GND.

Remove it and your sim will work properly (move the Vout label to the wire between D1 and RL.)

Comment: you're right, I should probably have written my comment as answer, thanks for making this Q&A complete!+1